# angular 1.6.1 '&' binding issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Problem:
When I bind '&' under ng-repeat(or without for that matter atm), I can't seem to trigger the parent scope's function.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="type in fC.types">
  <repeater type="type" someFn="fC.someFn()"></repeater>
</div>
```

Parent Controller

```
function formControllerFn(){
  var vm = this;
  this.types = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  this.someFn = function(){
    console.log("type");
  };
}
```

Repeater Component

```
formtest.component('repeater', {
  controller: repeaterFn,
  bindings: {
    type: '<',
    someFn: '&'
  },
  template: `<div><span>{{$ctrl.type}}</span> <span ng-click="$ctrl.someOtherFn()">remove me</span></div>`
});

function repeaterFn(){
  var vm = this;
  this.$onInit = ()=>console.log(this.type);
  this.someOtherFn = function(){
    console.log(vm.someFn);
    console.log("someOtherFn");
    vm.someFn();
  };
}
```

When clicked on `remove me`, it consoles the `vm.someFn` generic function and the text "someOtherFn" but doesn't trigger the parent `someFn`.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help or direction is appreciated!

[REPL Link](https://repl.it/FRD6/23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because your binding is configured incorrectly. Angular converts all camel case names to kebab case, `someFn -> some-fn`. You just need to update your input binding to be the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="type in fC.types">
  <repeater type="type" some-fn="fC.someFn()"></repeater>
</div>
```

#### [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/iWMShb7HDAglGwOyLTu4)

Comment: Thanks, but have you tried it on your end? I've tried it with and without those invocation but to no avail.
Not just '&' bind but one-way '<' bind also doesn't work if I replace it as such.
I'm guessing `ng-repeat` puts a new scope, but not sure how you can pass on through that one extra layer in the view.

Comment: Thanks Teddy! It's always the simple overlooking that does it. Totally forgot about the camel casing.
We might need to update the answer (here not in plunkr) one more time though. It needs to be `some-fn="fC.someFn()"` instead of `someFn="fC.some-fn"`
Thanks again! I'll vote it up once we've updated it.

Comment: Whoops edited the wrong someFn. Thanks for letting me know. Should be corrected now.

Comment: Accepted the answer. However, I feel that this question doesn't even merit to be in SO. It was Angular basics and forgot about it. Resorted to SO, as I was running against time and lost a couple of hours on a small step.
It'd be better to go back to drawing board and pull up some more reading materials if we dont know the basics at the first place.. haha